# Determine the last digit of the following number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Problem:** Determine the last digit of the following number $$\underbrace{7^{7^{7^{7...}}}}_{1001\text{ }7's}.$$

**My Attempt:** By Euler's theorem $7^4\equiv 1\pmod {10}\Rightarrow 7^7\equiv 3\pmod {10}.$ After this I am clueless.

**Edit $1$:** So I tried taking even and odd number of sevens and this is what I observed $$7^{7}\equiv 3\pmod{10}.$$ $$7^{7^{7}}\equiv 7\pmod{10}.$$ $$7^{7^{7^{7}}}\equiv 7^{7^{7*7^6}}\equiv \left(7^{7^{7}}\right)^{7^6}\equiv 7^{7^6}\equiv 3\pmod{10}.$$ Thus for an odd number of sevens it seems that the remaineder will be $7$ whereas for an even number of sevens the remainder will be $3.$

**Edit $2$:** We need to find $7^7\equiv 1\pmod 4$ therefore $7^{7^{7}}\equiv 7^{4k+1}\equiv 7\pmod {10}.$ Similarily $7^{7^{7^{7}}}\equiv 7^{7^{4k+1}}\equiv 7^7\equiv 3\pmod {10}.$ Also observe that $7^{7^{7}}\equiv 7^{2k+1}\equiv 3\pmod 4.$ If we have $5$ sevens $7^{7^{7^{7^7}}}\equiv 7^3\equiv 3\pmod{10}.$

Comment: What is $7^7$ congruent to modulo $4$?

Comment: $7\pmod 4$, right?

Comment: See whether this helps you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454511/unit-last-digit-of-the-number-777

Comment: @DanielFischer please see the edit and try to explain my observation.

Comment: It seems you computed $\bigl(7^7\bigr)^7$ rather than $7^{(7^7)}$.

Comment: Have you examined the function x^7 over Z_10?

Comment: I didn't understand your question since I am not aware of the symbols. Does $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ mean over the residue classes modulo $10$?

Comment: Let's denote $a\uparrow\uparrow 0=1$, and $a\uparrow\uparrow(k+1)=a^{a\uparrow\uparrow k}$. So you want to find $7\uparrow\uparrow 1001\bmod{10}$. By Euler's theorem, and $7\uparrow\uparrow 1001=7^{7\uparrow\uparrow 1000}$, you need to find $7\uparrow\uparrow 1000\bmod{4}$. By Euler's theorem again, you need to find $7\uparrow\uparrow 999\bmod{2}$. You can either see that $7^{\text{whatever}}\equiv 1\pmod{2}$, or go one step further and note $\text{everything}\equiv 0\pmod{1}$. So $7\uparrow\uparrow 999 \equiv 1\pmod{2}$, and therefore $7\uparrow\uparrow 1000\equiv 7^1 \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$,

Comment: from which we obtain $7\uparrow\uparrow 1001 \equiv 7^3 \equiv 3\pmod{10}$. The particular value $1001$ played no role, but we needed two steps, so $7\uparrow\uparrow k \equiv 3 \pmod{10}$ for all $k \geqslant 2$.

Answer (score 1):

As you observed, by Euler's theorem, the exponent works modulo $4$.  And $7$ happens to be congruent to $-1 (\bmod{4})$.  The exponent is a tower of $1000$ $7$'s, which, modulo $4$, is $-1$ raised to an odd power.  So modulo $10$, your tower of $1001$ $7's$ is $\equiv 7^{-1} \equiv 3 (\bmod{10}).$