# Method of calculating the last digit of $7^{49}$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I would like to point out the difference between $7^{7^7}$ and $7^{49}$. typically the notation $a^{a^{a^a}}$ means $a^{(a^a)}$. Heuristically, start from the top and work your way down. e.g. $2^{2^{{2^2}}} = 2^{(2^{({2^2})})} = 2^{(2^{4})} = 2^{16}=65536$.

Comment: The answer is $7$, as you calculated. Why do you say it's $3$?

Comment: The answer is $7$ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7%5E49+mod+10

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454511/unit-last-digit-of-the-number-777 and a few other sources

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-unit-digit-of-7-7-7

Comment: $7^{7^7} = 7^{823543} \ne 7^{49}$

Comment: @BasemFouda, $7^{7^7}$ and $7^{49}=7^{7^2}$ are entirely different numbers.

Comment: @zahbaz do you mean it is $7^{(7^7)}$ ?

Comment: @BasemFouda don't encourage the use of quora... they just copy-paste questions and answers from stackexchange to give the illusion that their website is participated on when in reality it rarely ever receives any original content of its own.

Comment: should I delete the question or should I leave it do you think?

Comment: In fact $$7^{7^7} \equiv 7^3\equiv 3\mod 10$$

Comment: @BasemFouda Don't delete this question because expressions like $7^{(7^7)}$ and $(7^7)^7$ are often mixed and it might help more people to distinguish them. The convention is that $a^{b^c}=a^{(b^c)}$

Comment: Yes, typically the notation $a^{a^a}$ means $a^{(a^a)}$. Heuristically, start from the top and work your way down. e.g. $2^{2^{{2^2}}} = 2^{(2^{({2^2})})} = 2^{(2^{4})} = 2^{16}=65536.$

Comment: I encourage you to answer your own question along with the correction. Your original solution was accurate.

Comment: I have edited the question please feel free to edit whatever you want

Answer (score 2):

$$7^{49}\equiv 7^1=7\mod 10$$ We can reduce the exponent modulo $\phi(10)=4$, which immediately gives the result $7$.

Answer (score 2):

notice that $7^2 \equiv 49 \equiv -1 \pmod {10}$

then we have

$$7^{49} \equiv 7^{32} \times 7^{16} \times 7 \equiv (7^{2})^{16} \times (7^{2})^{8} \times 7 \equiv(-1)^{16} \times (-1)^8 \times 7\equiv 7 \pmod {10}$$

thus the answer is 7.